# Why does the same game take 2.4-3.0x GPU power on a desktop with only 1.5x the FPS of the laptop?

Tags: gpu

I expected the same game with the same settings to have linear watts vs FPS, but it's not. Is this normal? If so, why is it non-linear?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cfsXEvQGQJ8

RTX 3080 16GB Laptop (ASUS ROG Strix SCAR 17) vs RTX 3080 10GB Desktop l 1440p

System:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Ryzen 9 5900X
- ASUS ROG X570 Crosshair VIII Hero ​
- CPU Cooler - be quiet! Dark Rock Pro 4
- GeForce RTX 3080 10GB
- 16Gb RAM DDR4 3600Mhz
- SSD - 2xSAMSUNG 970 EVO M.2 2280 1TB
- Power Supply CORSAIR RM850i 850W

Laptop ASUS ROG Strix SCAR 17

- GeForce RTX 3080 16GB
- Ryzen 9 5900HX
- 32Gb RAM DDR4

[image: Assassins creed side by side]

[image: CyperPunk side by side]

[image: Red-dead redemption side by side]

Comment: _"I expected the same game with the same settings to have linear watts vs FPS"_ - why?

Comment: same settings, really? then why is there a VAST quality difference, especially in textures and in distance-rendering, between the images? The comparisons are **not** performing the same task!

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two completely different pieces of equipment.

The desktop RTX 3080 is almost a year older than mobile RTX 3080.

Desktop version consumes up to 320W while mobile version only up to 115W.

Desktop version benchmarks 24419 and mobile version bechmarks 16023 ratings in G3D.

Desktop performance is then 76 points per watt and laptop performance is 139 points per watt.

So the laptop performs more with same amount of watts.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason I think is that laptop needs to be connected to the charger all the time of gaming and it heats more than a desktop. Heating is one of the reasons of dropping FPS. On the other hand desktop has fans more powerful than a laptop's cooling fan.

Answer (score 0):

Big unsorted list of possibilities:

- the measurement is inaccurate, or measuring different things. The desktop version is a separate card, the laptop version integrated. The power accounting and measurement circuitry is probably different.
- the hardware is not the same: just because it has the same consumer part number doesn't mean it's the same silicon. See "JustMe"'s answer.
- the hardware is running under different conditions; "Unimportant"'s comment about different voltage and frequency conditions. Increasing voltage does exponentially increase power consumption.
- the hardware is running in a different thermal throttling regime
- the settings may differ in game
- the settings may differ *out of game*; the reason Nvidia ship a "driver" pack of several hundred megabytes is that they maintain a number of compatibility shims and tweaks for popular games. These can dramatically accept performance and even appearance between "driver" update versions. It can be difficult to identify which of these are in effect. The drivers themselves may make different choices if they detect a "mobile" configuration.